# Primary contact's email of the Organization

Tags: apex

Does anybody know how to obtain primary contact for the **Organization**? The object itself has a field **PrimaryContact**, but that's a text field not a reference.
Any ideas better than `SELECT Id, Email FROM User WHERE (FirstName =: organization.PrimaryContact) OR (LastName = :organization.PrimaryContact)`

Answer (score 2):

The primary contact field on the organization object is just a text field and allows you to lookup users in the org but doesn't restrict it. The email for the primary contact does not appear to be stored in the org itself. The help doc for [changing the primary contact](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005352&language=en_US), simply states to do the following:

> Resolution You can change the primary contact for your company using
>   the instructions provided below:
>
> 1. Click on:
>
> Setup | Administration setup | Company Profile | Company Information.
>
> 1. Fill in the Primary Contact field with the appropriate name.
> 2. Save the Company Information change.
>
> This will successfully change the primary contact of your
>   organization.

Comment: Does anyone know what the implications of changing this field are? Does this contact receive certain emails? Are there other bits of functionality that rely on this info?